# Does any Hindu scripture tell us to never consider our enemy (or for that matter any other person) as weak or foolish?

Tags: knowledge

It is common wisdom that one should never underestimate his enemy under any circumstance.

I want to know if there is any such thing written in scriptures like - We should never view others as foolish or weak .

Answer (score 1):

[image]

> **sudurbalaṁ nāvajānāti kañcid yukto ripuṁ sevate buddhi pūrvam |
> na vigrahaṁ rocayate balasthaiḥ kāle ca yo vikramate sa dhīraḥ**
> He is a wise person who doth(does) not disregard(underestimate)
> even a weak foe(enemy); who proceeds with
> intelligence in respect of a foe, forbearingly
> watching for an opportunity; who doth(does) not
> desire hostilities(enemity) with persons stronger than
> himself; and who displayeth(displays) his prowess in appropriate time(69)
>
> **Vidura Niti**